# Как сравнить значения словаря с переменной.

Tags: python

Как сравнить значения словаря с переменной, по условию к примеру? Извиняюсь если не правильно выражаюсь.

Comment: Конкретизируйте условие. С примером, если можно.

Comment: Нужно уточнение, потому что словарь можно сравнить только со словарем.
А с переменной можно сравнивать либо ключ (взяв его из кортежа ключей, полученных с помощью keys() ), либо со значением по ключу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if dict_data['entry_name'] == variable:
    …
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне показалось, вы имеете ввиду, как узнать, есть ли в словаре значение, равное переменной. Это делается так:

```
if variable in dictionary.values():
    ...
```